# python pandas string column time rolling distinct count

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

As I want to count the unique number of column A in a moving time window(60 seconds):

```
fn = lambda x: len(np.unique(x)) 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'e'], 'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
                index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:32'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:02:03'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:02:25'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:03:06')])


df[['A']].rolling('60s').apply(fn)
```

I expect the result as

```
2013-01-01 09:01:00 1
2013-01-01 09:01:32 2
2013-01-01 09:02:03 2
2013-01-01 09:02:25 2
2013-01-01 09:03:06 2
```

however, the result is:

```
2013-01-01 09:01:00 a
2013-01-01 09:01:32 b
2013-01-01 09:02:03 a
2013-01-01 09:02:25 b
2013-01-01 09:03:06 e
```

what's the problem?

Comment: I add groupby by column `A`, but output is different. Can you check it?

Comment: check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707210/python-pandas-string-column-time-rolling-distinct-count/45707272#45707272) @xiaoxing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use column `B` instead `A`:

```
a = df[['B']].rolling('60s').apply(fn)
print (a)
                       B
2013-01-01 09:01:00  1.0
2013-01-01 09:01:32  2.0
2013-01-01 09:02:03  2.0
2013-01-01 09:02:25  3.0
2013-01-01 09:03:06  2.0
```

And if need convert to `int`:

```
a = df[['B']].rolling('60s').apply(fn).astype(int)
print (a)
                     B
2013-01-01 09:01:00  1
2013-01-01 09:01:32  2
2013-01-01 09:02:03  2
2013-01-01 09:02:25  3
2013-01-01 09:03:06  2
```

If no column you can create it:

```
a = df.assign(B=np.arange(len(df.index)))[['B']].rolling('60s').apply(fn).astype(int)
print (a)
                     B
2013-01-01 09:01:00  1
2013-01-01 09:01:32  2
2013-01-01 09:02:03  2
2013-01-01 09:02:25  3
2013-01-01 09:03:06  2
```

---

```
df['B'] = np.arange(len(df.index))
a = df[['B']].rolling('60s').apply(fn).astype(int)
print (a)
                     B
2013-01-01 09:01:00  1
2013-01-01 09:01:32  2
2013-01-01 09:02:03  2
2013-01-01 09:02:25  3
2013-01-01 09:03:06  2
```

EDIT1:

```
df['B'] = np.arange(len(df.index))
a = df.groupby('A')[['B']].rolling('60s').apply(fn).astype(int)
print (a)
                       B
A                       
a 2013-01-01 09:01:00  1
  2013-01-01 09:02:03  1
b 2013-01-01 09:01:32  1
  2013-01-01 09:02:25  2
e 2013-01-01 09:03:06  1
```

Comment: what about if there is no column B?

Comment: hi jezral, thx a lot. but what i want is to group by afther rolling, not before rolling

Comment: OK, so after rolling get `a->1, b->2, a>2, b->3, e->2`. then how get `1 2 2 2 2`? because if use `df['C'] = df['B'].rolling('60s').apply(fn).astype(int)` and then `df['D'] = df.groupby('A')[['C']].transform(fn)` output is different.

Comment: Or do you need aggreagate different way?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'e'], 'B': [0, 1, 0, 1, 4]},
                index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:32'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:02:03'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:02:25'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:03:06')]) df[['B']].rolling('60s').apply(fn) get the result

Comment: Hmmm, what about `df['C'] = pd.factorize(df['A'])[0]` and then `df['D'] = df['C'].rolling('60s').apply(fn).astype(int)` ? Do you need [`factorized column A`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#factorizing-values) ?

Comment: so why rolling.apply cannot used to string column?

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Simply try this way :

```
In [40]: import pandas as pd

In [41]: fn = lambda x: len(np.unique(x)) 
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
    ...:                 index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:00'),
    ...:                          pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:32'),
    ...:                          pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:02:03'),
    ...:                          pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:02:25'),
    ...:                          pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:03:06')])

In [42]: df[['B']] = df[['B']].rolling('60s').apply(fn).astype(int)

In [43]: df[['']] = df[['B']]

In [44]: df[['']]
Out[44]: 

2013-01-01 09:01:00  1
2013-01-01 09:01:32  2
2013-01-01 09:02:03  2
2013-01-01 09:02:25  3
2013-01-01 09:03:06  2

In [45]:
```